# jquery validate plugin, display one error at a time with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to know that how can I display the error messages on the bottom of the screen by using the jquery,validator plugin

also it's suppose to display the one error at a time.

for eg:-

name:- first error will be of name
email:- once name is validated then email's error will be displayed
website:-finally website's error.

And how to highlight the textbox of the field one by one same style:

< input type="text" name="name" >
< input type="text" name="email" >
< input type="text" name="website" >

< div id='error' >if name is blank then display only name is blank, if not then check for email and after that website< /div >

I don't know the how the whole coding is going to look like.

Please provide the coding snippet.

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    // Validation rules and messages go here

    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $("#myForm").find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("error");
        });
        $("#myErrorContainer").html("");
        if(errorList.length) {
            $("#myErrorContainer").html(errorList[0]['message']);
            $(errorList[0]['element']).addClass("error");
        }
    }
});
```

This will place one error at a time inside an element that has a `myErrorContainer` ID, and at the same time will highlight the element that is causing the error by adding a `.error` class to it.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks FreeOne,  The code snippet is working, but it's suppose to show the one error at a time, once the first validation is clear, then move to the others, also hightlighting is happening to all of them.

Comment: Yes' it's displaying the one error at a time, but hightlight is not happening at all :(

Comment: @dave - Please see the updated answer. This should work properly now.

Comment: @dave: glad to be of help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  wrapper: "li",
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo('#errordiv' );
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

replace errordiv with the id or class or whatever selector you have for the element you want to put the errors in